# When Uploading Videos to the api.videoindexer.ai and providing a callback URL, call back body message is empty

Tags: video, upload

I am not certain if I'm using the callbackUrl correctly or if there is an issue with the callback logic within the video indexer service. This callback is specifically for when you submit a video (Upload) it to the indexing service.

The following code segment works and generates the http POST request to the service and the service successfully imports the video and processes it. However, when it completes the callback post body is empty.

The Endpoint Definition that I am posting to:

```
https://api.videoindexer.ai/{location}/Accounts/{accountId}/Videos?name={name}[&privacy][&priority][&description][&partition][&externalId][&externalUrl][&callbackUrl][&metadata][&language][&videoUrl][&fileName][&indexingPreset][&streamingPreset][&linguisticModelId][&personModelId][&animationModelId][&sendSuccessEmail][&assetId][&brandsCategories][&accessToken]
```

Application posting the request (This code is working)

```
Config.ApiKey.Remove("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key");

VideosApi videosApi = new VideosApi(Config);

string callbackUrl = $"{FunctionApiEndpoint}/api/VideoIndexStatus?Code={FunctionApiCode}&clientId={FunctionApiClientId}";

ApiResponse<dynamic> result = await videosApi.UploadVideoAsyncWithHttpInfo($"Snag1 - {DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks}",
    Location,
    AccountId,
    privacy: "private",
    accessToken: Token.Data.Content.ToString().Replace("\"", ""),
    description: $"Test Video Segment - {DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks}",
    fileName: "Snag1.MP4",
    callbackUrl: callbackUrl,
    videoUrl: "https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/testmedia/Snag1.MP4",
    xMsClientRequestId: MsClientId);

Console.WriteLine(result.Data.Content);
```

The Function App / Webhook (This code is working)

```
[FunctionName("VideoIndexStatusRun")]
[return: ServiceBus("servicebus.queue.dev", Connection = "AzureWebJobsServiceBus", EntityType = EntityType.Queue)]
public async Task<IActionResult> VideoIndexStatusRun(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "VideoIndexStatus")] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log,
    ExecutionContext context)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string postdata = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

    log.LogInformation($"Postdata='{postdata}' | Postdata.Length='{postdata.Length}'");

    return new OkObjectResult(postdata);
}
```

Once the media has been processed and completed with analyzing the media in the portal "https://www.videoindexer.ai/media/library" it then sends a post message to my function app. However, the postdata is an empty string "" and the length = 0.

I am using Application Insights to inspect what is going on within my function app and I can see the message posted "Postdata='' | Postdata.Length='0'" within App Insights after the callback event from the videoindexer.ai service.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly after posting the question I realized what the answer is and to hopefully help someone else, like me, I realized that the callback process was not making a "body message" post but was returning it on the URL query string.

(I needed to read the documentation better...)

So I should have written my function app webhook method more like the following:

```
[FunctionName("VideoIndexStatusRun")]
[return: ServiceBus("servicebus.queue.dev", Connection = "AzureWebJobsServiceBus", EntityType = EntityType.Queue)]
public async Task<IActionResult> VideoIndexStatusRun(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "VideoIndexStatus")] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log,
    ExecutionContext context)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string message = $"{{\"id\":\"{req.Query["id"]}\",\"state\":\"{req.Query["id"]}\"}}";

    return new OkObjectResult(message);    
}
```

Now the returned values coming from the query string can be captured and forwarded on to my message processor.